# Regex for email but that can include whitespaces

Tags: c#, regex

I have a regex question, there is field for email of 60 characters. I got the regex working for email validation,
but I am not sure how to ignore whitespaces after the email but only upto the whole string is 60 chars. If there is
anything after 60 chars then its not valid.

```
^([A-Za-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-])([A-Za-z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-])*[@]([A-Za-z0-9.\-])([A-Za-z0-9.\-])*[.][A-Za-z.]{2,6}[ \t]+$
```

This should be a valid string (I am using quotes here to show string length)
'test1.test123@testtesttest.com                              '

This should not be a valid string
'test1.test123@testtesttest.com                              m'

Comment: The premise sounds a bit odd. Why would you limit the length to 60 characters *with* whitespace? I think it'd make more sense to remove the whitespace before saving it or whatever, because it does no good. Also why such a short limit? It's 2018, we have disk space.

Comment: [Trim](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3(v=vs.110).aspx) the string before testing it?

Comment: legacy system, i have no control over client side

Comment: You're probably going to trim the string anyway. I would trim it and compare the length of both before and after.

Comment: Trying to do this with one regexp is probably going to end up being pretty ugly. Regex isn't really made for this.

Comment: Try validating the length with and `if` statement then remove the spaces and validate using normal email regex

Comment: I am looking for a regex solution. Could have done in code but that is not an option I have.

Comment: Why do you need to do it solely in regex if you dont mind me asking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you insist on using Regex, you can use [positive lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to limit the total length of the string by simply adding the following right before your regex:

```
(?=.{6,60}$)
```

That would restrict the total length of the input string to be between 6 *(the minimum length of a valid email address)* and 60 *(your preferred maximum length)*.

You could also replace `[ \t]+` with `\s+` to match other whitespace characters *or with `\s*` to accept the input if it does or does not end with whitespace characters* if you're interested in matching all kinds whitespace characters.

Therefore, your pattern would look something like this:

```
^(?=.{6,60}$)([A-Za-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-])([A-Za-z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-])*[@]([A-Za-z0-9.\-])([A-Za-z0-9.\-])*[.][A-Za-z.]{2,6}\s*$
```

[Try it online](https://regex101.com/r/DH186T/2).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 0):

The mentioned regex does not work (see below)

[image]

So I've used mine and added validation for max limit of 60 chars

```
^(?!^.{60})(([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+|([a-zA-Z]{1}|[\w-]{2,}))@((([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\.([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\.([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\.([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])){1}|([a-zA-Z0-9]+[\w-]*\.)+[a-zA-Z]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,23})
```

This regex uses lookarounds syntax. You can see the output in various screenshots. You can check how it works at [here](https://regex101.com/r/yM3vL0/1).

Here `(?!^.{60})` matches max limit of 60 chars. And rest of regex syntax to validate the proper email address.

[image]

[image]

If also, see that the regex does not validate the string `test1.test123@testtesttest.com m`.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your efforts, this solution did not achieve all the requirements.